# TransformedDistribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I am trying to perform some calculations on a random variable that is the sum of a normal distribution and a truncated normal distribution.  My understanding is that using `TransformedDistribution` is recommended over `Convolve`.  For starters, I would like to plot the PDF of this distribution.  My attempt was the following

```
Plot[PDF[TransformedDistribution[
   x1 + x2, {x1 \[Distributed] 
     TruncatedDistribution[{1, Infinity}, NormalDistribution[]],
    x2 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[1, 1]}], 
  x], {x, -5, 5}]
```

This didn't return a result within an hour, so I think there must be a more efficient way to proceed.

Comment: This is a well-known result, see e.g. Nelson, "The sum of values from a normal and a truncated normal distribution."

Using that, your example has PDF `Erfc[1 + (1 - t)/2]/(2*E^((1 - t)^2/4)*Sqrt[Pi]*Erfc[1/Sqrt[2]])`.

[Here's the PDF in red, compared to histogram in orange of 10^7 RV from your transformed distribution](https://imgur.com/AdNw98c). 

If time permits, I'll post as answer with explanations, but that paper will get you what you want.

Comment: I chose this example specifically because it has a closed form solution, but Mathematica doesn't seem to take advantage of this.  This suggests there's something about `TransformedDistribution` that is the source of the disconnect.  Maybe some implicit assumption that is being made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want some *Mathematica* commands to obtain the desired result as opposed to just finding out the desired result.  Here's one way to do that:

```
pdf1 = PDF[TruncatedDistribution[{1, ∞}, NormalDistribution[0, 1]], x1][[1, 1, 1]]
```

[image: pdf for x1]

```
pdf2 = CDF[NormalDistribution[1, 1], y - x1]
```

[image: pdf for x2 = y - x1]

```
density = D[Integrate[pdf1*pdf2, {x1, 1, ∞}], y]
```

[image: pdf for y]

```
(* Estimate density with a large random sample *)
n = 1000000;
xx2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 1], n];
xx1 = RandomVariate[TruncatedDistribution[{1, ∞}, NormalDistribution[0, 1]], n];
sum = xx1 + xx2;
sdk = SmoothKernelDistribution[sum];

(* Plot both *)
Plot[{PDF[sdk, y], density}, {y, -2, 8},
 PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.03], LightGray}, {Thickness[0.001], Red}},
 PlotLegends -> {"Smooth kernel density", "True density"}]
```

[image: True and estimated density for y]

Comment: Can you provide some intuition as to why having it integrate the distribution directly works, whereas using TransformedDistribution does not?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want:  `Integrate[pdf1*pdf2, {x1, 1, \[Infinity]}]` is the cumulative distribution function of $Y$:  $\text{Pr}(Y\leq y)$.  Then the density is just the derivative of that with respect to $y$.  So while there is a closed-form for the density, it doesn't appear that *Mathematica* can find a closed-form for the cdf.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case of a truncated normal convoluted with a normal distribution, the answer can be adapted from https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121899/sum-of-truncated-normal-with-two-normal-distributions.  However, I would still like to know how to proceed in general.